# Local Notification crashes Ionic/Angular/Cordova app on button click

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, local

This is the code that I am using with Ionic/Cordova's local notification plugin in my home.page.ts file:

```
 notifs(time) {
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
       id: 1,
       title: 'Test App',
       text: 'Enter Text',
       icon: '../test.png'
       trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
    });
  }
```

In my html template, I have this button click which calls the above function:

```
<ion-button (click)="notifs(12)" [fill]="fill" slot="">Hours</ion-button>
```

Every time this button is clicked, the Android app crashes.

I would like to click on the button, which will trigger a phone notification (even when the user is not on the app) at a delayed time for the same time every day. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**:
I removed the id, icon and the button click, so it looks like the below:

```
 notifs(time) {
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
       title: 'Test App',
       text: 'Enter Text',
       trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)}
    });
  }
```

Now the issue is that everytime the trigger is reached and the notification is supposed to occur, the app crashes.
The notifications work fine on iOS.
I have tried debugging with the Chrome android debugger, but nothing happens.

Comment: Please add crash report or errors that you get in the console/logcat

Comment: Could you please see what happens if you a) remove the `icon` property and b) change the id for a random number instead of being 1? I'm asking this just to find what exactly is causing the crash, so that we can see how to fix it.

Comment: Without a log it's hard to help you.....Maybe the missing COMMA after "icon: ../test.png"??

Comment: @ Pankaj How would I see crash reports/console error on an android device?  @ sebaferreras When I remove icon and id properties (I don't really need them right now), it still crashes.  @ emandt, good point! I removed the entire icon line and it still crashes

Comment: @PankajSati Nothing shows on the console when using the Chrome debugger, before it crashes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My android app crashed every time I tried to schedule a notification, and I finally found that it was because of the trigger property.

My case was:

`trigger: { every: { hour: this.hour, minute: this.minute } }`

if this.hour or this.minute wasn't a valid value, the app crashed. Try to change the value specified at the property 'at', maybe the expression 'new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600' is generating an invalid value for this property.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem in August 2th 2023, here is the solution i found... The plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications doesn't work in android 12 (API 32) and 13 (API 33) You have to install the fquirin's fork.

Run
1- cordova plugin add https://github.com/fquirin/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

2- `npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/local-notifications`

N.B: API 32 and API 33 Require the user's permission to display the notifications don't forget to add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the Platform/android/App/Src/Main folder:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

Hope it'll help!